# this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-addin

This AddIn is not always firing

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisApplication_NewMail);
    }
```

I have code in my method to pop up a messagebox when a new message arrives. (testing).

however I've noticed that this is NOT always working. I sent myself messages and sometimes it triggers the event handler and other times it does nothing. How can I make it so that it's always triggered.

Comment: What kind of account are you using? Exchange? POP3/SMTP? IMAP4?

Comment: Exchange server/Outlook Desktop client

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate question

Comment: Was the message received while Outlook was running? If not, no new mail notification will be raised. the best you can do is see the new messages being downloaded into the OST store from the server. Items.ItemAdd event on the Inbox folder will fire in that case.

Comment: Well when I press "Start" in VS13, it will launch outlook automatically. I checked the Developer -> Com Add-Ins and I see that it's "Checked" (loaded). However the Event is not firing on new incoming mail. It also appears that outlook needs to be open for a few minutes (didn't get the exact number of minutes) before it catches everything. So is there a delay caused by Outlook to actually load my code and begin executing?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on that line of your code? Does it get hit? Do you see the even fire in OutlookSpy (click Application button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Events tab, look at the log at the bottom of the window)?

Comment: I did set a breakpoint. It does hit the breakpoint in the StartUp. Does not hit the ThisApplication_NewMail() method at all

Comment: meant to say that it doesn't hit the method all the time. It does it sometimes

Comment: Did you check in OutlookSpy? Just to be sure, we are talking about **new** mail notifications, not just synching of the unread messages that were delivered to the online store when Outlook was not running? You get the new mail toaster popup for them, right?

Comment: I get the Toast notifications on my Win 8 machine but the code doesn't always execute upon new mail arrival. My code also checks to make sure they are not read.  inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");

Answer (score 0):

This event fires when one or more new mail messages arrive in the users’ Inbox. But when you receive 16 or more items at once, the event does not even fire.

You may consider using the *NewMailEx* or *ItemAdd* event.

Also I'd recommend reading the series of articles reagrding the NewMail event issue, here is the entry point - [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/) .

Comment: Well I haven't even tried 16 messages at once. I did one at a time. Which of the three would you recommend for new messages before rule processing occurs?

Comment: The simplest way is to handle the NewMailEx event. But the most reliable way is to use a timer for checking new email items.

Comment: If I use a timer, isn't it possible to miss some message that may arrive during the time interval?